# Paternity vs. Paternal vs. Parental Leave

Tags: word-choice, expressions, word-usage, terminology, business-language

Which one is the most commonly used to describe a leave taken by a father in the United States?

Answer (score 2):

The three options are not really comparing like to like, as *parental leave* can refer to leave taken by either parent, and so will appear in different contexts.

The most common term for time off taken by a new mother is *maternity leave*, and so it is unsurprising to see that ***paternity leave*** is the more popular counterpart in the Google NGram, though this is not exclusive to the United States:

[image: Google NGram comparing "maternity leave", "paternity leave", "parental leave", and other terms]

*Maternal leave* or *paternal leave* sounds off to me. To my ear they would refer to leave that is somehow for example nurturing or protective, respectively (by stereotype).

*Parental leave* is terminology I associate with the Commonwealth, so I am surprised to see it neck and neck with *family leave*, which was mandated via the [Family and Medical Leave Act of 1993](http://www.dol.gov/whd/fmla/) (after several presidential vetoes).